# Multiple if statements or else-if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

Is any difference in writing multiple if statements than only one and then adding else-if ones?

Like here:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Guess the number from 1/5");
        int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (number == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You guessed wrong");
        }
        if (number == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You guessed wrong");
        }
        /* else if (number == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You guessed wrong");
        }
         * .......up to number 5
         */
        if (number == 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You guessed wrong");
        }
        if (number == 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You guessed wrong");
        }
        if (number == 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You're right!");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

I know that there is much better way of writing this but the difference is the only thing what matters here for me. It might has an impact on performance...

Comment: There are two differences: a) In one case __all__ conditions will __allways__ be tested (a performance loss). b) The logic is different, if one code block changes data other ifs may get true..so different things may happen. Ususally go for the else if construct!

Comment: Stop worrying about performance and worry about readability first. I'd be more concerned you have 4 identical code blocks. Only worry about performance when it's actually running slow.

Comment: As mybirthname's answer shows, using `else` provides a graceful way to handle the case when no matches are found. It may be a default or an error depending on your application, but it's good practice to have something there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use multiple if, you are going to check them one by one. If you use `if,else if` when you enter in one of them no more checks will be made. In your case it will be better to use `else if`, because number can only have one of this values.

```
            Console.WriteLine("Guess the number from 1/5");
            int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (number == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You guessed wrong");
            }
            else if (number == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You guessed wrong");
            }             
            else if (number == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You guessed wrong");
            }
            else if (number == 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You guessed wrong");
            }
            else if (number == 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You're right!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong guess");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

`With else if you will have better performance ! Also you can check this things with debug ! You should learn to use it !

Answer (score 0):

Generally to avoid using a huge if-else statement is to use a `switch` clause

```
switch(number)
{
    case 1:
        // this part will run if number is 1
        break; // break is required after cases

    case 2:
        // this part will run if number is 2
        break;

    case 3:
    case 4:
        // you can also join cases together
        // this part will run if number is either 3 or 4
        break;

    default:
        // the default case runs when no case was matched
        break;
}
```

In your case, using a `switch` can simplify your code to this

```
switch (number)
{
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("You guessed wrong");
        break;

    case 5:
        Console.WriteLine("You're right!");
        break;
}
```

Comment: If you can map the conditions to a number

Comment: *switch case* dont come close to *if-elseif*. It is for specific cases only.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you can just do the following:

```
  Console.WriteLine("Guess the number from 1/5");
  int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  var result = number == 5  ? "You're right!" : "You guessed wrong";

  Console.WriteLine(result );


  Console.ReadKey();
```